# L2 caching with datanucleus. Authentication required

Tags: heroku, memcached, jpa-2.0, datanucleus, spymemcached

I am using datanucleus for JPA (I am using it for both mongo and postgreSQL in case it matters) on Heroku. I would like to use a Level 2 cache, but the memcached services provided by Heroku require authentication. From [the datanucleus L2 cache configuration documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/cache.html#memcached) it seems this is not possible, but maybe I'm missing something. Alternatively, maybe I'm missing a different service on Heroku that could work.

Right now I have L2 cache turned off because, as I understand it, this is the only way to ensure consistency across JVMs.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: It seems I can't authenticate onto Mongdb either. How can that be?!?

Comment: I figured out the mongo issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373869/datanucleus-mongodb-with-authentication/17374074

Comment: so if they require authentication to use some L2 cache (which one? you haven't said which L2 cache provider it is) define how authentication credentials can be supplied

Comment: which one: memcached (I prefer spymemcached because I'm using it already, but I can use xmemcached if necessary). Authentication is Username/Password.

Comment: so why not add support for it to the DN cache plugin ? The spymemcached support consists of very few lines https://sourceforge.net/p/datanucleus/code/HEAD/tree/platform/cache/trunk/src/java/org/datanucleus/cache/spymemcached/SpymemcachedLevel2Cache.java  and contribute it back when done

Comment: I will look into that. Changing the code is, presumably, easy enough, but I found setting up the project, even with maven, to be a challenge, so setting it from the source could be very difficult.