# Datanucleus Mongodb with authentication

Tags: mongodb, jpa, heroku, datanucleus

I am using datanucleus for JPA on Heroku with mongodb (mongolabs). Even when I set these properties:

```
datanucleus.ConnectionPassword=YYYYY
datanucleus.ConnectionUserName=XXXXX
```

I get `PersistenceException: Authentication of the connection failed for datastore heroku_app2765673 with user XXXXXXX`

Does datanucleus support connecting to mongodb with a password? It seems to know my username, so I assume so. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Removing and readding my mongolabs account seems to have fixed this. Don't know what the actual problem was, but it clearly wasn't datanucleus.